# How to add v-model to html input dinamically added in component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have this component, then, after an asynchronous request I need to create a new input and give a v-model bidding to it, it is possible?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="newInputsWrapper">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      foo:''
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    //Simulating asynchronous request
    setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('newInputsWrapper').innerHTML = '<input type="text" v-model="hereAnymodel">'
    //....maybe I will need to add more generated inputs...
    },2000);
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Comment: Write your input element in the template, hidden with a  v-if="asyncDone" that is controled by the asyc request?

Comment: well, the problem is that I dont know how many inputs I will need to add, so, I will like to give v-model to several generated inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vue you don't modify the html/template with selectors, at least not in the common case. Make your asynchronous request modify a variable in your component. Then use your that variable to render things in your template.

You would get something like this. Here we populate the `fields` variable with some labels and ids. The ids are mapped to our form data variable named `form`. We populate it to prevent possible `v-model` funkyness on non-existing variables. We can later use our `form` variable to do all kind of things.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>All kind of things</h2>

    <template v-for="field in fields">
      <label :key="field.id">{{ field.label }} <input type="text" v-model="form[field.id]" /></label>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      fields: [],
      form: {}
    };
  },

  watch: {
    fields(fields) {
      for (const field of fields) {
        if (this.form[field.id] === undefined) {
          this.$set(this.form, field.id, "");
        }
      }
    },

    form: {
      deep: true,
      handler(newForm) {
        console.log("Looks like our data has been changed!", newForm);
      }
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    //Simulating asynchronous request
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.fields = [
        { id: "a", label: "Label a" },
        { id: "b", label: "Label b" },
        { id: "c", label: "Label c" },
        { id: "d", label: "Label d" }
      ];
    }, 2000);
  }
};
</script>

<style>
label {
  display: block;
}
</style>
```

[image: Edit Vue Template]

Comment: I have made some changes as I put in a bug it seems. I also added a watcher so you can see how the data changes. You don't really need it other than for that debugging log.